# Is it a code smell to set a flag in a loop to use it later?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, clean-code

I have a piece of code where I iterate a map until a certain condition is true and then later on use that condition to do some more stuff.

Example:

```java
Map<BigInteger, List<String>> map = handler.getMap();

if(map != null && !map.isEmpty())
{
    for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        fillUpList();

        if(list.size() > limit)
        {
            limitFlag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    logger.info("\n>>>>> \n\t 6.1 NO entries to iterate over (for given FC and target) \n");
}

if(!limitFlag) // Continue only if limitFlag is not set
{
    // Do something
}
```

I feel setting a flag and then using that to do more stuff is a code smell.

Am I right? How could I remove this?

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove it if its working.

Comment: Why do you feel it's a code smell?   what kind of specific problems can you foresee when doing this which wouldn't happen under a different structure?

Comment: Avoid the term “code smell”. From an interpersonal point of view, it stinks in a major way.

Comment: @gnasher729 Just out of curiousity, which term would you use instead?

Comment: -1, your example makes no sense. `entry` is nowhere used inside the function loop, and we can only guess what `list` is. Is `fillUpList` supposed to fill `list`? Why doesn't it get it as a parameter?

Comment: I'd reconsider your use of whitespace and empty lines.

Comment: There's no such thing as code smells.  "Code smell" is a term invented by software developers who want to hold their nose when they see code that doesn't meet their elitist standards.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And when people type, they aren't speaking, but we often say that "[someone] said [something]" on the internet. It's just a metaphor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I normally would agree with you 100%! ... But, I've been struggling lately to replace the term "smell" with what I understand it to essentially mean: "An idiom or code pattern that suggests we may have organized this code poorly ..." ... And, I think flags *are* often suggestive of a better solution in OOP languages. Not that there always is one; but, that it's worth taking a second look ...

Comment: `fillUpList` takes no input and has no discernible return value. Is it modifying a global?

Comment: @BenCottrell "A possible indication of a problem".

Comment: There are too many issues with that code to be concerned with just the flag.

Comment: @svidgen The thing is, "smell" doesn't have anywhere near that meaning either.

Comment: @Feathercrown Disagreed. When I smelled the faint smell of "rotten eggs" in my house last month, the problem wasn't the smell. The smell was actually quite tolerable. The problem was the natural gas leak coming from my fireplace ... And sure, when I open my fridge and am bombarded with a rancid smell, I want to get rid of the smell. But, the smell is primarily an indication that I've waited far too long to clean out my fridge...

Comment: @svidgen Ah, I see.

Comment: It's a *function*. It has side-effects, and returns a value that's only meaningful in (presumably) exceptional circumstances. If that's the case then the function should return `void`, receive its list as a parameter, and throw a proper exception if it can't do its job. IMO a function that takes no parameters and alters state, indeed *smells*. I'd suggest putting up your *actual code* (the whole scope, and all its glorious context) on [codereview.se].

Comment: I hate the term "code smell" just because it's aesthetically displeasing. What's wrong with "problem with the code" or even  "antipattern" ?

Comment: This is tangential to question but `(map != null && !map.isEmpty())` seems to indicate a likely problem in `handler.getMap()`. It might not always be possible but I would try to avoid billion dollar mistake here (words of inventor, not mine) and require handler to always return non-null value.

Comment: The issue is saying something is a "red flag" or "antipattern", or "problem with the code" means you've identified an explicit problem.  When you find "code smell" it just means you've been alerted to the *possibility* of a problem by certain cues.  It is hardly unique to software development; in many contexts one can find this metaphor being used to indicate suspicion of an unseen problem.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: So you are implying that it should return an empty `Map` ?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha Yes - see [this presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) by Hoare (person who, among other things, invented NULL) - there is bunch of articles about the same as well but I thought that word of inventor might carry some weight... Empty map is perfectly valid case so there is no need to replace it by null. In such case you don't even _need_ `if` in your code - pure `for` is sufficient (you may want to keep logging but for doesn't need to be in `if` making code simpler).

Comment: It's redundant to check "if not empty" before iterating over a collection.

Comment: @kevincline, checking for emptiness of the map is redundant _for the iterating_ but it is _not redundant in this case_ because you want to log the fact that the map is empty.

Comment: @siegi: Right. I missed that.

Answer (score 70):

There's nothing wrong with using a Boolean value for its intended purpose: to record a binary distinction.

If I were told to refactor this code, I'd probably put the loop into a method of its own so that the assignment + `break` turns into a `return`; then you don't even need a variable, you can simply say

```
if(fill_list_from_map()) {
  ...
```

Comment: Actually the smell in his code is the long function which needs to be split into smaller functions. Your suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: A better phrase that describes the useful function of the first part of that code is finding whether the limit will be exceeded after it accumulates something from those mapped items. We can also safely assume that `fillUpList()` is some code (which OP decides not to share) that actually uses the value `entry` from the iteration; without this assumption, it would look like the loop body didn't use anything from the loop iteration.

Comment: @Kilian: I just have one concern. This method will fill up a list and will be returning a Boolean which represents that list size exceeds a limit or not, so the name 'fill_list_from_map' does not make it clear that what does the Boolean returned represent (it failed to fill up, a limit exceeds, etc). As the Boolean returned is for a special case which ain't obvious from function name. Any comments ? PS: we can take command query separation into consideration too.

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha You are right, and I had the exact same concern when I suggested that line. But it's unclear which list the code is supposed to fill. If it's always the same list, you don't need the flag, you can simply check its length afterward. If you do need to know whether any *individual* fill-up exceeded the limit, then you do have to transport that information outside somehow, and IMO the command/query separation principle isn't a sufficient reason to reject the obvious way: via the return value.

Comment: A boolean *variable* is a good deal broader and less dubious than a flag algorithmically. If I have time, I'll post an answer ... but, I think it's worth mentioning -- you're instinct here seems to be to refactor. Now, I'm not sure if the presence of the flag hinted at that for you; but, there's definitely a smell here. I think it's worth articulating what you think is "stinky" and suggestive of the need to refactor.

Comment: Uncle Bob says on page 45 of _Clean Code_: "Functions should either do something or answer something, but not both. Either your function should change the state of an object, or it should return some information about that object. Doing both often leads to confusion."

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha My suggestion would be to apply DDD principles and have a `enum` return value with possible values that clearly express what is meant, e.g. `LIMITED` and `NOT_LIMITED`.

Comment: @CJDennis Is Uncle Bob against status return codes? Because that's basically what that return value is - did this operation succeed (complete the list fill-up), or did it error out with a "list-too-big" error. -- Depending on how picky you were, you might want to encode such an error response as an int, and then have different "succeeded", "list-too-big" and "source-list-unavailable" error codes, but I personally don't see a reason to get persnickety about it.

Comment: @R.M. Robert Martin also thinks that if you make an error that costs your employer money, you should write them a check for that amount. You simply cannot take his dictums literally.

Comment: @R.M. Yes, he is. If it's a genuine error, it should throw an Exception. If it's not an error, the status should be checked with a method or a (protected) property. PHP (and many older languages) like to return status codes, which is one of the bad things in my opinion. I can't use the method and assume it succeeded, I have to check for an error condition every time. Uncle Bob is against that because it reduces readability and flow of ideas.

Answer (score 25):

It is not necessarily bad, and sometimes it is the best solution. But setting flags like this in nested blocks *can* make code hard to follow.

The problem is you have blocks to delimit scopes, but then you have flags which communicate across scopes, breaking the logical isolation of the blocks. For example, the `limitFlag` will be false if the `map` is `null`, so the "do something"-code will be executed if `map` is `null`. This may be what you intend, but it could be a bug which is easy to miss, because the conditions for this flag is defined somewhere else, inside a nested scope. If you can keep information and logic inside the tightest possible scope, you should attempt to do so.

Comment: This was the reason I felt that it's a code smell, as the the blocks are not completely isolated and can be hard to track later. So I guess code in @Kilian 's answer the closest we can get ?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: It is hard to say since I don't know what the code is actually supposed to do. If you only want to check if the map contains at least one item which a list larger than limit, I think you can do it with a single anyMatch expression.

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: the scope problem can easily be solved by changing the initial test to a guard clause like `if(map==null || map.isEmpty()) { logger.info(); return;}` This will, however, work only if the code we see is the full body of a function, and  the `// Do something` part is not required in case the map is null or empty.

Answer (score 14):

I'd advise against reasoning about 'code smells'.  That's just the laziest possible way to rationalize your own biases.  Over time you'll develop a lot of biases, and a lot of them will be reasonable, but a lot of them will be stupid.

Instead, you should have practical (i.e., not dogmatic) reasons for preferring one thing over another, and avoid thinking that you should have the same answer for all similar questions.

"Code smells" are for when you *aren't* thinking.  If you're really going to think about the code, then do it right!

In this case, the decision could really go either way depending on the surrounding code.  It really depends on what you think is the clearest way to think about what the code is doing. ("clean" code is code that clearly communicates what it's doing to other developers and makes it easy for them to verify that it is correct)

A lot of times, people will write methods structured into phases, where the code will first determine what it needs to know about the data and then act on it.  If the "determine" part and the "act on it" part are both a little complicated, then it can make good sense to do this, and often the "what it needs to know" can be carried between phases in Boolean flags.  I would really prefer that you gave the flag a better name, though.  Something like "largeEntryExists" would make the code a lot cleaner.

If, on the other hand, the "// Do Something" code is very simple, then it can make more sense to put it inside the `if` block instead of setting a flag.  That puts the effect closer to the cause, and the reader doesn't have to scan the rest of the code to make sure that the flag retains the value you would set.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is a code smell (cue downvotes from everyone who does it).

The key thing for me is the use of the `break` statement. If you didn't use it then you would be iterating over more items than required, but using it gives two possible exit points from the loop.

Not a major issue with your example, but you can imagine that as the conditional or conditionals inside the loop become more complex or the ordering of the initial list becomes important then it's easier for a bug to creep into the code.

When the code is as simple as your example, it can be reduced to a `while` loop or equivalent map, filter construct.

When the code is complex enough to require flags and breaks it will be prone to bugs.

So as with all code smells: If you see a flag, try to replace it with a `while`. If you can't, add extra unit tests.

Comment: +1 from me. It's a code smell for sure and you articulate why, and how to handle it, well.

Comment: @Ewan: `SO as with all code smells: If you see a flag, try to replace it with a while` Can you elaborate on this with an example ?

Comment: Having multiple exit points from the loop may make it harder to reason about, but in this case so would refactoring it to make the loop condition depend on the flag - it'd mean replacing `for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())` with `for (Iterator<Map.Entry<BigInteger, List<String>>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext() && !limitFlag; Map.Entry<BigInteger, List<String>> entry = iterator.next())`. That's an uncommon enough pattern that I'd have more trouble understanding it than a relatively simple break.

Comment: @James_pic my java is a bit rusty, but if we are using maps then I would I would use a collector to sum up the number of items and filter out those after the limit. However, as I say the example is "not that bad" a code smell is a general rule that warns you of a potential problem. Not a sacred law you must always obey

Comment: Don't you mean "cue" rather than "queue"?

Comment: yes, that was a deliberate mistake, well done for spotting it!! :)

Comment: @Ewan I couldn't see a clean way to do this with map. My experience is that map doesn't play especially nice with early-outs (you've got to either keep going past the point where you know you've finished, or use nasty exception-based control flow hacks), although there might be a trick I don't know about (I'm more familiar with Scala's implementation of this stuff than Java 8's). In any case, it might be instructive to give examples of cleaner code.

Comment: @James_pic I don't think its too useful to get caught up in the example tbh. The question is about the general practice, not the specifics. Either you can refactor a particular case into something cleaner or not. It's still a code smell

Answer (score 0):

Just use a name other than limitFlag that tells what you are actually checking. And why do you log anything when the map is absent or empty? limtFlag will be false, all you care about. The loop is just fine if the map is empty, so no need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a boolean value to convey information you already had is bad practice in my opinion.  If there is no easy alternative then it's probably indicative of a bigger issue like poor encapsulation.

You should move the for loop logic into the fillUpList method to have it break if the limit is reached. Then check the size of the list directly afterwards.

If that breaks your code, why?

Answer (score 0):

First off the general case: Using a flag to check if some element of a collection meets a certain condition is not uncommon. But the pattern I've seen most often to solve this is to move the check in an extra method and directly return from it (like Kilian Foth described in [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/364419/52522)):

```java
private <T> boolean checkCollection(Collection<T> collection)
{
    for (T element : collection)
        if (checkElement(element))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Since Java 8 there is a more concise way using [`Stream.anyMatch(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```java
collection.stream().anyMatch(this::checkElement);
```

In your case this would probably look like this (assuming `list == entry.getValue()` in your question):

```java
map.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.size() > limit);
```

---

The problem in your specific example is the additional call to `fillUpList()`. The answer depends a lot on what this method is supposed to do.

Side note: As it stands, the call to `fillUpList()` does not make much sense, because it does not depend on the element you are currently iterating. I guess this is a consequence of stripping down your actual code to fit the question format. But exactly that leads to an artificial example that is difficult to interpret and thus hard to reason about. Therefore it is so important to provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So I assume that the actual code passes the current `entry` to the method.

But there are more questions to ask:

- Are the lists in the map empty before reaching this code? If so, why is there already a map and not just the list or set of the `BigInteger` keys? If they are not empty, why do you need to *fill up* the lists? When there are already elements in the list, isn't it an *update* or some other computation in this case?
- What causes a list to become larger than the limit? Is this an error condition or expected to happen often? Is it caused by invalid input?
- Do you need the lists computed up to the point you reach a list larger than the limit?
- What does the "*Do something*" part do?
- Do you restart the filling after this part?

This are only some questions that came to my mind when I tried to understand the code fragment. So, in my opinion, *that is the real code smell*: Your code does not clearly communicate the intent.

It could either mean this ("all or nothing" and reaching the limit indicates an error):

```java
/**
 * Computes the list of all foo strings for each passed number.
 * 
 * @param numbers the numbers to process. Must not be {@code null}.
 * @return all foo strings for each passed number. Never {@code null}.
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException if any number produces a list that is too long.
 */
public Map<BigInteger, List<String>> computeFoos(Set<BigInteger> numbers)
        throws InvalidArgumentException
{
    if (numbers.isEmpty())
    {
        // Do you actually need to log this here?
        // The caller might know better what to do in this case...
        logger.info("Nothing to compute");
    }
    return numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            number -> number,
            number -> computeListForNumber(number)));
}

private List<String> computeListForNumber(BigInteger number)
        throws InvalidArgumentException
{
    // compute the list and throw an exception if the limit is exceeded.
}
```

Or it could mean this ("update until first problem"):

```java
/**
 * Refreshes all foo lists after they have become invalid because of bar.
 * 
 * @param map the numbers with all their current values.
 *            The values in this map will be modified.
 *            Must not be {@code null}.
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException if any new foo list would become too long.
 *             Some other lists may have already been updated.
 */
public void updateFoos(Map<BigInteger, List<String>> map)
        throws InvalidArgumentException
{
    map.replaceAll(this::computeUpdatedList);
}

private List<String> computeUpdatedList(
        BigInteger number, List<String> currentValues)
        throws InvalidArgumentException
{
    // compute the new list and throw an exception if the limit is exceeded.
}
```

Or this ("update all lists but keep original list if it becomes too large"):

```java
/**
 * Refreshes all foo lists after they have become invalid because of bar.
 * Lists that would become too large will not be updated.
 * 
 * @param map the numbers with all their current values.
 *            The values in this map will be modified.
 *            Must not be {@code null}.
 * @return {@code true} if all updates have been successful,
 *         {@code false} if one or more elements have been skipped
 *         because the foo list size limit has been reached.
 */
public boolean updateFoos(Map<BigInteger, List<String>> map)
{
    boolean allUpdatesSuccessful = true;
    for (Entry<BigInteger, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        List<String> newList = computeListForNumber(entry.getKey());
        if (newList.size() > limit)
            allUpdatesSuccessful = false;
        else
            entry.setValue(newList);
    }
    return allUpdatesSuccessful;
}

private List<String> computeListForNumber(BigInteger number)
{
    // compute the new list
}
```

Or even the following (using `computeFoos(…)` from the first example but without exceptions):

```java
/**
 * Processes the passed numbers. An optimized algorithm will be used if any number
 * produces a foo list of a size that justifies the additional overhead.
 * 
 * @param numbers the numbers to process. Must not be {@code null}.
 */
public void process(Collection<BigInteger> numbers)
{
    Map<BigInteger, List<String>> map = computeFoos(numbers);
    if (isLimitReached(map))
        processLarge(map);
    else
        processSmall(map);
}

private boolean isLimitReached(Map<BigInteger, List<String>> map)
{
    return map.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.size() > limit);
}
```

Or it could mean something entirely different… ;-)